# SQL PHP How do I update a foreign key based on the primary key of another table?

Tags: php, sql, key, match

I've looked around and tried solutions, but for some reason this is not working. I have a table for upcoming_albums with an albums_id as its primary, automatically incrementing key. In my upcoming_albums_tracks table, I want its albums_id to update to have the same value as the one in albums_id whenever I create a new album.

Here's the method in my php class file

```
public function create ($title, $content, $date, $price){ 

$db = Dbclass::getDB();
$query = "INSERT INTO upcoming_albums (albums_title, albums_content, albums_date, albums_price, albums_img_path)
            VALUES (:title, :content, :date, :price, :path)";

$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->bindParam(':title', $title, PDO::PARAM_STR, 50);
$statement->bindParam(':content', $content);
$statement->bindParam(':date', $date);
$statement->bindParam(':price', $price, PDO::PARAM_STR, 10);
$statement->bindValue(':path', $this->target_path, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$statement->execute();

$query = "UPDATE upcoming_albums_tracks
            SET albums_id = upcoming_albums.albums_id
            FROM upcoming_albums_tracks
            WHERE upcoming_albums_tracks.albums_title = upcoming_albums.albums_title";

$statement = $db->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();
```

}

Creating the album works just fine, but the albums_id of the upcoming_albums_tracks table does not alter from NULL to the value it's supposed to be.

Here's a visual of the issue.

upcoming_albums table:

[image]

upcoming_albums_tracks table (I need albums_id to be the same, not NULL)

[image]

*UPDATE* This is my method that handles inserting the tracks. Note that each album has multiple tracks, so first my create method is called, and then foreach track inserted, I run the following method. The issue now is nothing gets inserted at all:

```
public function createTrack ($title, $track, $index) {

        $db = Dbclass::getDB();
        $lastInsertId = $db->lastInsertId();    

        $query = "INSERT INTO upcoming_albums_tracks (albums_id, albums_title, albums_track, albums_track_path, albums_track_file)
                    VALUES (" . $lastInsertId . " :title, :track, :path, :file_name)";

        $statement = $db->prepare($query);
        $statement->bindParam(':title', $title, PDO::PARAM_STR, 50);
        $statement->bindParam(':track', $track, PDO::PARAM_STR, 50);
        $statement->bindValue(':path', $this->tracks[$index]['target_path'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindValue(':file_name', $this->tracks[$index]['file_name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $statement->execute();

    }
```

The weird part is that if I try to echo $lastInsertId, it gives me the proper number.

Comment: When you insert the record, you basically need to get the ID of that last inserted record and use it to make the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$lastInsertId = $db->lastInsertId();

$query = "UPDATE upcoming_albums_tracks SET albums_id = $lastInsertId FROM upcoming_albums_tracks WHERE upcoming_albums_tracks.albums_title = upcoming_albums.albums_title";
```

Comment: Please see the updated section of my question. I incorporated your advice, but now nothing is being created inside the tracks table at all.

Comment: Forgot a comma, D'oh!!

Comment: I selected you as the best answer. The other answers were great, but I appreciate the fact that you gave me a specific answer for this specific problem, rather than referencing an example.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to get the ID of the last record that was inserted. To accomplish that in MySQL, you can use:

```
 $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
```

Take a look at this [enter link description here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_lastid.asp)

Comment: Tried this: $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=muzy", "root", "");  $albums_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);    $query = "INSERT INTO upcoming_albums_tracks (albums_id)  VALUES (" . $albums_id . ")";

Got this error: mysqli_insert_id() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given in